# Nginx reverse proxy SSL termination with docker - too many redirects

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm a bit out of my element trying to deploy a Laravel (php) application via docker. Everything works great until I try to use SSL certs via Lets Encrypt, which triggers a redirect loop I'm unable to resolve.

```
upstream app {
    server app1520925178:80;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name app.example.com;

    # handle future LE refreshes
    location /.well-known {
        root /var/www/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;

    server_name app.example.com;

    ssl_protocols              TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers                ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
    ssl_session_cache          shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout        24h;
    keepalive_timeout          300s;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.example.com/privkey.pem;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        #include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

        # Handle Web Socket connections
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** It "randomly" started working a few minutes after this post was created. Still not 100% sure why it would take time to "propagate", if anyone has insight into that, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: What do you use as DNS service? I had a similar problem with Apache and it was an issue caused by Cloudfare.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Cloudflare as your DNS service (not registering domains over it, but managing your DNS records with it) and have Cloudflare's protection enabled (orange cloud symbol), this can occur.

Note the following paragraph in [this support article by Cloudflare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000219871-Why-does-Flexible-SSL-cause-a-redirect-loop-):

> If the origin server happens to be configured to redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS, server responses back to Cloudflare are encrypted and since Cloudflare is expecting HTTP traffic, it keeps resending the same request, resulting in a redirect loop. This causes browsers to display "The page isn’t redirecting properly" or "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" errors.

So, the flexible SSL is most likely your issue. You can turn that off by going to the crypto page in your Cloudflare control panel and setting the SSL mode to "Full (strict)":
[image: Set Cloudflare SSL mode to full]

This resolved my issues on an Apache system, but I'm very confident it's the same source of problems with nginx.

Answer (score -1):

Changing the crypto setting to "Full (strict)" may help:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your text to explain how it answers the specific question that has been asked, and also please provide details of how the service you discuss may be accessed (since all you have provided is an image); also, please clarify whether or not there are other similar options. Thanks.